# MvvmCross DataBinding To Modify Individual Item in Android ListView

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, android-listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to dynamically modify the items in a List (ObservableCollection) of a ViewModel and have those changes get updated in the View via MvvmCross bindings.  My eventual goal is that when a user clicks on a list item, I will pop up a dialog asking them to edit that item.  When the dialog is dimissed, the viewmodel will get updated (through an ICommand I assume) and that modified value will be now be in the list.

I haven't looked into dialogs yet, so for now I am just trying to toggle a boolean value each time a list item is clicked and have that value changed in the MvxListView.  I have the MxvListView in my View bound to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel and have an MvxCommand   that is getting called when an item is selected.  All this is working and I can see the value getting changed in the debugger, however, the new values are not being displayed in the MvxListView.  So my question is: How do I get modified data in individual items in an ObservableCollection to bind to an MvxListView?

All of the examples I have seen online use ObservableCollection for dynamic binding but they only ever Add or Delete items.  I haven't found any examples of modifying the items.  If I change the code in my MvxCommand from modifying the data to adding or deleting an item, the list will get updated.  So that tells me I'm close I think.

Rather than copy paste the code in here, I created a sample project on github here to look at:
https://github.com/smulrich/breaktimer

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace
`Breaks[index] = b;`
with
`Breaks[index] = new DailyBreak() { Reason = b.Reason, TimeOfDay = b.TimeOfDay, Enabled = b.Enabled };`

or more reasonable, you should realize `INotifyPropertyChanged` for class `DailyBreak`
Diffrent among List, ObservationCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged, please refer to [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha)

Comment: +1 for the "more reasonable" suggestion. Best way forwards is for `DailyBreak` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - e.g. it could inherit from `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged`